# if pass an object as parameter, it is freed when the sub or function ends?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Public Sub EliminaPedido(Num As Integer, Hoja1 As Worksheet)
```

and at the main form:

```vb
Private Sub bBaja_Click()
    Dim x10 As New Excel.Application
    Dim ArchivoDestino As Workbook
    Dim R As String
    R = "Año " & Year(Now)
    Set ArchivoDestino = x10.Workbooks.Open(Ruta & "\Registro pedidos.xlsx", 0)
    Dim M As Integer
    M = MsgBox("Desea eliminar el pedido " & Me.Range("H2").Value & " emitido a " & Me.Range("E11").Value & "?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Pedidos de Elementos")
    If M = 6 Then EliminaPedido Me.Range("H2").Value, ArchivoDestino.Worksheets(R)
    ArchivoDestino.Close True
End Sub
```

When `EliminaPedido` ends, the object `Hoja1` is freed, or into that sub I must use `set Hoja1 = Nothing`?

Comment: The parameter Hoja1 will go out of scope at the end of the sub. There is nothing you need to do.  Do not assign the value of nothing to Hoja1 as this could cause a memory leak.  To understand why read up on the difference between passing parameters ByRef and ByVal.  In the code you posted you have implicitly declared Hoja1 as ByRef as this is the default action for VBA.

Comment: @freeflow `Do not assign the value of nothing to Hoja1 as this could cause a memory leak` - how? `read up on the difference between passing parameters ByRef and ByVal` - what difference does that make regarding the alleged memory leak?